# Bootstrap list-group with multiple checkboxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi have a couple of list groups, like this:

```html
<div class="list-group">
<a href="javascript:callFunction(1)" class="list-group-item" id="title1">Title 1</a>
<a href="javascript:callFunction(2)" class="list-group-item" id="title2">Title 2</a>
<a href="javascript:callFunction(3)" class="list-group-item" id="title3">Title 3</a>
</div>
```

That list shows just fine.  Each item is in what appears to be a row and the href is applied across the entire row as opposed to just on the text.

What I'm am trying to do is something similar, however with two leading checkboxes.  Each of these checkboxes makes a different javascript call to the call within the link.  Here's what I have...formed within a list-group `<ul>` because how else can I group these three distinct items?

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline my-checkbox-margin" id="HS" name="HS-1" value="HS-1" checked onchange="javascript:callOtherFunction(1);"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" id="MS" name="MS-1" value="MS-1" onchange="javascript:callStillAnotherFunction(1);">
   <a href="javascript:callFunction(1)" id="title1">Other Title 1</a>   
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline my-checkbox-margin" id="HS" name="HS-2" value="HS-2" checked onchange="javascript:callOtherFunction(2);"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" id="MS" name="MS-2" value="MS-2" onchange="javascript:callStillAnotherFunction(2);">
   <a href="javascript:callFunction(2)" id="title2">Other Title 2</a>   
</li>
```

In the end, I am unable to hover over the "row" and click the link.  I have to actually hover over the link text.

These won't show correctly given the lack of bootstrap, but they should be simple enough...

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to be able to hover over the entire row to get the action I have when I click the link.